# Mount Drive based on connection with if else statement (applescript)

Tags: macos, finder, network, applescript

can someone please help me out with this script.  Where am I going wrong?

```
Try
set ping to (do shell script "ping -c 2 " 192.168.1.240)

if ping contains "64 bytes" then
tell application "Path Finder"
    try
        mount volume "smb://192.168.1.240/home"
        mount volume "smb://192.168.1.240/shared"
        mount volume "smb://192.168.1.240/video"
        mount volume "smb://192.168.1.240/music"

Display Dialog "Mapped Drives to 192.168.1.240 Network."

Else
tell application "Path Finder"
    try
        mount volume "smb://192.168.0.240/home"
        mount volume "smb://192.168.0.240/shared"
        mount volume "smb://192.168.0.240/video"
        mount volume "smb://192.168.0.240/music"

Display Dialog "Mapped Drives to 192.168.1.240 Network."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your `set ping to` statement should have the closing quote after the IP address
2. In general you are missing a number of `end` statements. Each `try` should have a corresponding `end try`, each `tell` should have an `end tell`, each `if` should have an `end if`.
3. The `try` statements should surround the script action, not inside them. So move them before the `tell` statements. As you are using them without the 'on error' clause, the try statements aren't very useful - but no harm.
4. The application should be just "Finder"

Here's a briefer example:

```
try
    set ping to (do shell script "ping -c 2 192.168.1.240")
    
    if ping contains "64 bytes" then
        try
            tell application "Finder"
                mount volume "smb://192.168.1.240./music"
            end tell
        end try
        display dialog "Mapped Drives to 192.168.1.240 Network."
        
    else
        try
            tell application "Finder"
                mount volume "smb://192.168.0.240./music"
            end tell
        end try 
        display dialog "Mapped Drives to 192.168.0.240 Network."
        
    end if
end try
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  Can multiple drives be mounted at once on a single try or do I have to have a statement for each drive mounted?

Comment: You're welcome. Sure, you can add those others back just like you had them. I just cut it back to one to test and posted that to be brief.